# Как правильно сделать сборку с помощью Maven?

Tags: maven, macos, java

Пытаюсь собрать проект скаченный с [github](https://github.com/jmatheus/videoPlayer). После команды:

```
$ mvn package
```

Появляются кучу ошибок:

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects... 
 [INFO]
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 [INFO] Building videoplayer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom
 (8 KB at 8.2 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.jar
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.jar
 (32 KB at 320.7 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
 (11 KB at 152.7 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom
 (14 KB at 195.2 KB/sec) 
 Downloading:
 http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.jar
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.jar
 (30 KB at 323.3 KB/sec) 
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ videoplayer ---
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. 
 [INFO] skip nonexisting resourceDirectory /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/mainresources
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ videoplayer ---
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.pom
 (867 B at 4.7 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-1.9.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-1.9.1.pom
 (4 KB at 49.4 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.pom
 (692 B at 4.3 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.pom
 (688 B at 4.1 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.9.1/plexus-compilers-1.9.1.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/1.9.1/plexus-compilers-1.9.1.pom
 (2 KB at 7.2 KB/sec) 
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.jar
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.jar
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.jar
 (21 KB at 64.1 KB/sec) 
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar
 (5 KB at 9.6 KB/sec) 
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.jar
 (14 KB at 28.4 KB/sec) 
 [INFO] Compiling 27 source files to /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/target/classes
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/WorkerTeste.java:[30,39] inconvertible types found   : java.lang.Object required: int 
 [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/exceptions/VlcNaoEncontradoException.java:[17,2] cannot find symbol symbol  : constructor Exception(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable,boolean,boolean) location: class java.lang.Exception
 [INFO] 2 errors 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 [INFO] Total time: 7.125s 
 [INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 13 14:31:50 CET 2014 
 [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project videoplayer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
 [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/WorkerTeste.java:[30,39] inconvertible types [ERROR] found   : java.lang.Object 
 [ERROR] required: int
 [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/exceptions/VlcNaoEncontradoException.java:[17,2] cannot find symbol 
 [ERROR] symbol  : constructor Exception(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable,boolean,boolean)
 [ERROR] location: class java.lang.Exception 
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1] 
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Что это значит? Раньше я не использовал Maven. Как-то плохо ориентируюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Из всего мавеновского вывода обратите внимание на строки, начинающиеся с `[ERROR]`:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

Ошибка компиляции - наводит на мысль, что проблема не в мавене, а в коде.

> [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/WorkerTeste.java:[30,39] **inconvertible types found**   : java.lang.Object required: int
>
> [ERROR] /Users/DerKode/Downloads/videoPlayer-master/src/main/java/br/juliovaz/videoplayer/exceptions/VlcNaoEncontradoException.java:[17,2] **cannot find symbol symbol**  : constructor Exception(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable,boolean,boolean) location: class java.lang.Exception

Видим, что проблема в двух классах WorkerTeste (строка 30)  и VlcNaoEncontradoException (строка 17).

Если посмотрим исходники, увидим в первом случае:

```
int progress = (int) evt.getNewValue(); //попытка откастовать Object в int
```

во втором случае:

```
super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace); // попытка вызвать родительский конструктор Exception(String, Throwable, boolean, boolean). Вероятно, код под Java 7, а вы компилируете более ранней версией jdk.
```

Comment: Но у меня в систему тоже стоит Java 7. Как при сборке сослаться на новую версию SDK?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

Comment: > Как при сборке сослаться на новую версию SDK?

Если в pom.xml явно не указана версия Java, то можно переопределить переменную окружения $JAVA_HOME.